# Image Resize angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this function to resize and generate base64.

```
function toBase64Image(img_path) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        window.imageResizer.resizeImage(function (success_resp) {
            q.resolve(success_resp);
        }, function (fail_resp) {
            q.reject(fail_resp);
        }, img_path, 1920, 1080, {
            imageDataType: ImageResizer.IMAGE_DATA_TYPE_URL,
            quality: 100,
            pixelDensity: true,
            storeImage: false,
            photoAlbum: false,
            format: 'jpg'
        });

        return q.promise;
    }
```

When I send the image to the server, it arrives, but with a black background and the small image. Can someone help with a tip?

Comment: No, because nobody know which image resizer you are using.

Comment: I'm using this resizer PhoneGap-Image-Resizer

Comment: I can't help you with this but you should try to provide more information, like which plugin, environment and potential example image in this case.

Comment: *black background and the small image* 2 different ? did you try sending it without resize ?

Comment: I need to send a base64-encoded image to the server, after taking a photo, I use the above function to resize and base64 encode, this function belongs to PhoneGap-image-Resizer plugin. The image arrives on the server, for example it has 1920x1080, but only one part is the image and all the rest is a black background. I do not know if this is the best plugin to do this, if anyone can give a plugin tip for base64 encoding, I appreciate it.